# Count total price of items

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code like this:

```
if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM price WHERE user_id='$user_id'")){
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        while ($data = $result->fetch_object()){
            if ($data->user_test_type == '1'){
                $a = 10000;
            }elseif ($data->user_test_type == '2'){
                $b = 15000;
            }elseif(!empty($data->user_test_1)){
                $c = 3000;
            }elseif (!empty($data->user_test_2)){
                $d = 3000;
            }
            $Amount_array = array($a, $b, $c, $d); 
            $total = array_sum($Amount_array);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I count the total of `($a, $b, $c, $d)` items? The result `($total)` is not correct. Is there any better way?

Comment: Side note: Learn to use parameterized queries.

Comment: You're overwriting the variables each time through the loop. You need to add to `$total`, not replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not intentionally overwriting `$a`, `$b`, `$c` or `$d` for each row, you can use conditional aggregation to get the sum directly from the database.

```
SELECT sum(CASE
             WHEN user_test_type = '1' THEN
               10000
             WHEN user_test_type = '2' THEN
               15000
             WHEN user_test_1 = ''
                   OR user_test_1 IS NULL THEN
               3000
             WHEN user_test_2 = ''
                   OR user_test_2 IS NULL THEN
               3000
             ELSE
               0
           END) sum
       FROM price
       WHERE userid = ?;
```

Note, that I assumed that `user_test_type` is of a string type. If it is of some numeric type, remove the single quotes in `user_test_type = '1'` and `user_test_type = '2'`. I also assumed that `user_test_1` and `user_test_2` are strings and by empty you mean the empty string or a `NULL` value. If they aren't strings but some numeric type, remove `user_test_1 = '' OR` and `user_test_2 = '' OR`.

Comment: thanks, this code look like be true but not working correctly. i test it but it not count all of items and only count first value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to the variables each time through the loop, not replace them. Then combine them into `$total` at the end.

```
if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM price WHERE user_id='$user_id'")){
    $a = $b = $c = $d = 0;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        while ($data = $result->fetch_object()){
            if ($data->user_test_type == '1'){
                $a += 10000;
            }elseif ($data->user_test_type == '2'){
                $b += 15000;
            }elseif(!empty($data->user_test_1)){
                $c += 3000;
            }elseif (!empty($data->user_test_2)){
                $d += 3000;
            }
        }
    }
    $Amount_array = array($a, $b, $c, $d); 
    $total = array_sum($Amount_array);
}
```

Comment: thanks, this code look like be true but not working correctly. i test it but it not count all of items and only count first value.

Comment: Please edit the question. Add sample table contents and what you expect the result to be.